# failure of startup to login screen -18.04

Tags: login-screen, disk-usage, bleachbit

Was using bleach bit to cleanup. PC has very low disk space. Now won't start up and is showing stopping user manager for UID 123. NB: PC shut down unanticipated and now no start up to login.

Answer (score 0):

In the [BleachBit FAQ](https://docs.bleachbit.org/doc/frequently-asked-questions.html#q-why-does-bleachbit-take-a-long-time-more-than-five-minutes-while-filling-up-by-hard-drive) see the section "Q: Why does BleachBit take a long time (more than five minutes) while filling up by hard drive?" There are steps to delete the ~/.cache/ directory.

If the normal [Ubuntu recovery mode](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode) does not work, use a [live CD or thumb drive](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCdRecovery).